# Equivalent Criteria for convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

My textbook of Metric Spaces describes the following equivalent criteria for convergence of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ :

$(i)~ \bigcap \{ \overline {x_n~|~n \in S}~|~S \subseteq \mathbb N, S$ infinite $\} = \{z\} $

$(ii)~dist~(z, \{x_n~|~n \in S \} )=0$ for every infinite subset $S$ of $\mathbb N$

$(iii)~$ Every open subset of $X$ that contains $z$ includes a tail of $\{x_n\}$

Also, the book defines convergence as follows :

$(iv)~$ Suppose $X$ is a metric space , $z \in X, \{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $X$. We say that $\{x_n\}$ converges to $z$ in $X \iff$ every open subset of $X$ that contains $z$ includes a tail of $\{x_n\}$

> But, the book also proceeds to say that the intersection of the closures of the tails of the sequence may be a singleton set without the sequence converging.

If the intersection of the closures of the tails of the sequence is a singleton set, then, by $(iii)$  Every open subset of $X$ that contains $z$ includes a tail of $\{x_n\}$

Which means by the definition $(iv)$  the set must be convergent under all cases?

What mistake might I be making?

Thank you very much for your help in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Let's call this property ($*$):

> ($*$) The intersection of the tails of $(x_n)$ is a singleton.

Your mistake is using (iii). The problem is that property ($*$) is *strictly weaker* than property (i).

For a counter-example, consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric, and the sequence $(x_n)$ given by $x_n=n$ is $n$ is even and $x_n=1$ if $n$ is odd. Then $(x_n)$ does not converge to $1$, but the intersection of the closure of the tails is the singleton $\left\{1\right\}$.

---

In fact, ($*$) is equivalent to convergence of $(x_n)$ (for any sequence $(x_n)$) if and only if the metric space is *compact*.

Answer (score 0):

$X$ may not be complete:

Let $X=\mathbb Q$ and take  $\left \{ r_{n} \right \}= \left \{ r\in \mathbb Q:r^{2}<2 \right \}$. Then the closure of every tail contains $x=\sqrt 2$ but $r_{n}\not \to \sqrt 2$ bcause $\sqrt 2\not \in \mathbb Q$